# Trying to rewrite url for a custom module with an extra custom variable using PathAuto

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I needed to create a custom module to show product information. It's a custom module because the data comes from a remote database. This module has a block which I add to a basic page.
(It was my first drupal website from some time ago, and I know it's not the conventional method.)

Now in this module I do a $_get call from a product id in the url. For example if the page is /product?id=50, it will get the product of id 50 and show that information in the block.
Now at request of the client the url needs to look like /product/50 for SEO reasons. Also true for categories for example categories/boots instead of categories/category=boots

I tried using http access file but I can't get it to work. Also see: [Drupal does rewrite url but can't load css/themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76475/drupal-does-rewrite-url-but-cant-load-css-themes)

Now they suggested to use Pathauto module. So I've installed the module. But it won't create those url's taking the custom variables into account. 
Is there a way so I make Pathauto take into account those extra variables needed for my $_get? Or is there a better method?

I've never used this module before, so noob proof advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I've written a custom module with the hooks url inbound and outbound

(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)

This worked for me. I still don't know why the .htaccess approach didn't work tough.

Comment: Could you please share your code has an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2-step problem.

1) User friendly URLs

Pathauto is the wrong solution. Setting URLs in custom modules is the job of [`hook_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['product'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_product_view',
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_product_view($id = 0) {
  //Do database call here for product id = $id
}
```

Using this simple example, you can visit the page `product/50`. Drupal will then call the `mymodule_product_view` function with the second parameter (in this case 50) as the arguement.

2) Creating a block to show product information

What you need to get is the product name or id. If that is already in the url you can use `arg(2)` assuming your URL is "examples.com/product/50". Here is the api page for Drupals [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.

Ideally you would then do database calls etc. with this arguement within a custom modules block. You can find out how to create a block in custom code [here](https://drupal.org/node/1104464)